# Shortcut for creating run config for current class in intellij 14?

Tags: intellij-idea

I find myself repeating the following process all the time:

1. Run -> Edit config -> Add new config -> Application

2. Name: class name of current file

3. Main class: class name of current file

4. OK

I am wondering if there is a short cut to automate all these steps.

Comment: If you hit ctrl+shift+A and type "Create run" you should be able to select "Create Run Configuration", but for me the pop up menu seems bugged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the current class without manually creating run configuration.

If your class contains main method (or if it is a JUnit class or other type of file that IntelliJ knows how to run), just hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and run configuration will be created for you.

On Mac OS X it is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.